# Unable to view the complete PDF document in salesforce classic Preview and Lightning Quick View

Tags: lightning, opportunity, attachment, notes

We have PDF document attached in the Opportunity notes and attachment section in salesforce. When we click on Preview in salesforce classic it wont show us Page 5 and 6 of the PDF.

Similarly, In Lightning when we click on the attachment the quick view wont show us the Page 5 and 6.

But , If we download the PDF file and open it through Adobe /Web it shows the page 5 and 6 .

Is it the limitation of salesforce? How we can overcome this.

Please advise.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you please add more details? Or what you have tried? Like if you are creating that PDF, try by adding one more blank page in there and check if it is being shown as 7th page or may be add this as 5th page and test?

Comment: @AdityaVijay no code involved to create the PDF. It is normal procedure where the Notes and attachment is added to the Opportunity manually by the user. Later when the user try to preview it bot hin classic and lightning it shows blank page for 5 and 6 . But when we download and view it it shows 5 and 6

Comment: It does not have such limitation to show only 4 page. This is what i can say.